# How can I print this PDF and fill an A4 page?

Tags: pdf, print-design, mac, retina

I have [this PDF](http://madebyfiga.com/assets/images/500x500%20pixel%20grid%20for%20tablet.pdf). It's a simple grid created in Pixelmator with lines every 500 pixels. I want to use it as a template for drawing over a Wacom tablet.

For some reason, no matter what I do, print preview won't display the full grid. I've tried changing scaling, etc to no avail.

The image is 2880 x 1800 (the resolution of my MacBook Pro Retina 15").

This seems like a really simple thing to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw it up in a vector drawing program instead --- the preview is dropping lines 'cause the pixels are dropping out. The image prints okay scaled to fit a letter or legal-sized page.